# React Native and Apollo: Can't find variable: document

Tags: javascript, react-native, apollo, react-router-dom, react-dom

I am getting the error that has been stated on the title, and I am not sure how to get rid of it and make my app run properly.

I have been trying to solve it but can't find a solution yet. The only thing I found that was related to my error was this comment: "You cannot use document in React Native, you can create a backdrop behind the menu then on press backdrop you can hide it." written by Fayeed. Although this may seem to be my answer, I am not sure how to create that backdrop. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import news from './components/News';
import eating from './components/Eating';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import {ApolloProvider} from 'react-apollo';
import {HttpLink} from 'apollo-link-http';
import {InMemoryCache} from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const client= new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({uri:'https://api-useast.graphcms.com/v1/ck25kwqhb10bg01cx4o1i5czu/master'}),
  cache:new InMemoryCache()
})

const routing = (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={LoginForm} />
    <Route path="/news" component={News} />
    <Route path="/eating" component={Eating} />
  </Router>
)


ReactDOM.render((
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    routing
  </ApolloProvider>
),
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.3",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.4",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.16",
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "graphql": "^14.5.8",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I want to be able to load my app without any errors.

Comment: Are you really trying to do react-native here? It looks like you are trying to create a typical react application for the web instead.

Comment: ReactDOM is for inserting react on html nodes. There is no `document` in the context of a mobile application.

Comment: @FranreySaycon yup, I was wrong. I have just fixed it; had to use router-native and not DOM. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, I had to download react-router-native and not react-router-DOM. That was it. Instead of:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
mport ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import {ApolloProvider} from 'react-apollo';
import {HttpLink} from 'apollo-link-http';
import {InMemoryCache} from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
```

I had to do:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route, Link, NativeRouter as Router} from 'react-router-native';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import {ApolloProvider} from 'react-apollo';
import {HttpLink} from 'apollo-link-http';
import {InMemoryCache} from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
```

And replace that DOM render for a class component.